# How to align the text file after copy and paste?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk, copy-and-paste

I copied column 7,8 and 9 from file 1 into columns 7,8 and 9 in file 2 producing a new file 3. the produced file (file 3) is not aligned as the original files, How can I edit it to preserve the alignment ?

I used the command:

```
    awk '(getline line < "file 1") > -1 {split(line,a); $7 = a[7]; $8 = a[8]; $9= a[9]} 1' file 2 > file 3
```

file 1:

GRM in vacuum

192700

```
1GRM     C1    1  17.188   0.311  13.994 -0.5971  0.0204 -0.0724
1GRM     C2    2   0.094   0.383   0.005  0.4831 -0.8709 -0.2204
1GRM     C3    3   0.091   0.524   0.008 -0.7098  0.3449 -0.3952
1GRM     C4    4  17.185   0.596   0.007 -0.4066 -0.4079  0.1701
2GRM     C1    5  17.187   0.738   0.016  0.1844 -0.5441 -0.4893
2GRM     C2    6   0.090   0.815   0.011  1.1631 -0.2289 -0.8340
2GRM     C3    7   0.091   0.957   0.014 -0.4473 -0.2423 -0.3223
2GRM     C4    8  17.184   1.028   0.009 -0.4822  0.0086 -0.4791
3GRM     C1    9  17.189   1.171   0.004 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
```

file 2:

GRM in vacuum

192760

```
1GRM     C1    1   0.061   0.071  14.000 
1GRM     C2    2   0.184   0.142  14.000
1GRM     C3    3   0.184   0.284   0.000
1GRM     C4    4   0.061   0.355   0.000
2GRM     C1    5   0.061   0.497  14.000
2GRM     C2    6   0.184   0.568   0.000
2GRM     C3    7   0.184   0.710   0.000
2GRM     C4    8   0.061   0.781   0.000
3GRM     C1    9   0.061   0.923   0.000
3GRM     C2   10   0.184   0.994  14.000
3GRM     C3   11   0.184   1.136  14.000
3GRM     C4   12   0.061   1.207  14.000
4GRM     C1   13   0.061   1.349  14.000
4GRM     C2   14   0.184   1.420  14.000
4GRM     C3   15   0.184   1.562   0.000
4GRM     C4   16   0.061   1.633  14.000
5GRM     C1   17   0.061   1.775   0.000
5GRM     C2   18   0.184   1.846   0.002
5GRM     C3   19   0.184   1.988   0.001
5GRM     C4   20   0.061   2.059   0.000
```

file 3:

GRM in vacuum

192760

```
1GRM C1 1 0.061 0.071 14.000 -0.5971 0.0204 -0.0724
1GRM C2 2 0.184 0.142 14.000 0.4831 -0.8709 -0.2204
1GRM C3 3 0.184 0.284 0.000 -0.7098 0.3449 -0.3952
1GRM C4 4 0.061 0.355 0.000 -0.4066 -0.4079 0.1701
2GRM C1 5 0.061 0.497 14.000 0.1844 -0.5441 -0.4893
2GRM C2 6 0.184 0.568 0.000 1.1631 -0.2289 -0.8340
2GRM C3 7 0.184 0.710 0.000 -0.4473 -0.2423 -0.3223
2GRM C4 8 0.061 0.781 0.000 -0.4822 0.0086 -0.4791
3GRM C1 9 0.061 0.923 0.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
3GRM C2 10 0.184 0.994 14.000 0.1033 0.4238 -0.8983
3GRM C3 11 0.184 1.136 14.000 -0.0426 -0.1083 -0.8554
3GRM C4 12 0.061 1.207 14.000 -0.2814 -0.0363 -0.9146
4GRM C1 13 0.061 1.349 14.000 0.7722 0.4317 -0.4379
4GRM C2 14 0.184 1.420 14.000 -0.5701 0.2915 -0.3098
4GRM C3 15 0.184 1.562 0.000 0.4572 0.1368 0.1921
4GRM C4 16 0.061 1.633 14.000 -0.0747 -0.5492 -0.1254
5GRM C1 17 0.061 1.775 0.000 0.3071 0.9864 -0.8679
5GRM C2 18 0.184 1.846 0.002 -0.7815 -0.8144 -0.0069
5GRM C3 19 0.184 1.988 0.001 -0.0089 0.1174 0.2548
5GRM C4 20 0.061 2.059 0.000 0.7953 0.1404 -1.1225
6GRM C1 21 0.061 2.201 14.000 -0.0370 0.1705 -0.3342
6GRM C2 22 0.184 2.272 14.000 -0.2619 0.4221 -0.6572
6GRM C3 23 0.184 2.414 14.000 -0.4540 -0.3948 -0.6204
6GRM C4 24 0.061 2.485 14.000 -0.1499 -0.2942 -0.5181
```

the Format I wanted to have is the same format as file 1 and 2 (spaces between columns)

I tried the below commands as advised by schrodigerscatcuriosity and steeldriver, However I still have a problem from line 10002 to the end, please check below the commands I tried and the output:

```
    awk '(getline line < "file_1") > -1 {split(line,a); $7 = a[7]; $8 = a[8]; $9= a[9]} 1' file_2 | rev | column -t | rev > file_3

    awk 'BEGIN{fmt="%8s%7s%5d%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.4f%8.4f%8.4f"} (getline line < "file 1") > -1 {n = split(line,a)} n > 6 {$0 = sprintf(fmt,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[7],a[8],a[9])} 1' "file 2" > file 3
```

both of them gave me the below:

```
 2499GRM     C2 9994  15.433   7.810   0.001  0.2740 -0.1307  0.2597
 2499GRM     C3 9995  15.433   7.952   0.000 -0.0604 -0.1317  0.2130
 2499GRM     C4 9996  15.310   8.023   0.001 -0.0362 -0.0640 -0.3092
 2500GRM     C1 9997  15.310   8.165   0.001 -0.0183 -0.0765 -0.0458
 2500GRM     C2 9998  15.433   8.236   0.000 -0.2414  0.3310  0.3241
 2500GRM     C3 9999  15.433   8.378   0.000 -0.2669  0.3179  0.8367
 2500GRMC410000   15   8.449   0.000   0.000  0.5860  0.8426  0.0000 #(This line is 10002)
 2501GRMC110001   15   8.591   0.000   0.000  0.5939 -0.1623  0.0000
 2501GRMC210002   15   8.662   0.000   0.000  0.4561 -0.1660  0.0000
```

I tried to increase the spaces using

```
 awk 'BEGIN{fmt="%10s%9s%7d%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.4f%8.4f%8.4f"} (getline line < "file 1") > -1 {n = split(line,a)} n > 6 {$0 = sprintf(fmt,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[7],a[8],a[9])} 1' "file 2" > file 3
```

as advised by  , and I got the below output:

```
   2499GRM       C3   9995  15.433   7.952   0.000 -0.0604 -0.1317  0.2130
   2499GRM       C4   9996  15.310   8.023   0.001 -0.0362 -0.0640 -0.3092
   2500GRM       C1   9997  15.310   8.165   0.001 -0.0183 -0.0765 -0.0458
   2500GRM       C2   9998  15.433   8.236   0.000 -0.2414  0.3310  0.3241
   2500GRM       C3   9999  15.433   8.378   0.000 -0.2669  0.3179  0.8367
   2500GRM  C410000     15   8.449   0.000   0.000  0.5860  0.8426  0.0000 # (This line is 10002)
   2501GRM  C110001     15   8.591   0.000   0.000  0.5939 -0.1623  0.0000
   2501GRM  C210002     15   8.662   0.000   0.000  0.4561 -0.1660  0.0000
   2501GRM  C310003     15   8.804   0.000   0.000  0.4524 -0.1486  0.0000
   2501GRM  C410004     15   8.875   0.000   0.000 -0.2143  0.4926  0.0000
   2502GRM  C110005     15   9.017   0.000   0.000 -0.2203  0.2975  0.0000
   2502GRM  C210006     15   9.088   0.000   0.000 -0.2375 -0.0458  0.0000
   2502GRM  C310007     15   9.230  14.000   0.000 -0.2338 -0.4862  0.0000
   2502GRM  C410008     15   9.301  14.000   0.000 -0.1438 -0.0725  0.0000
```

The original file looks as below at the same part (at line 10002):

file 1:

```
 2499GRM     C3 9995  15.167   8.231  13.994 -0.0604 -0.1317  0.2130
 2499GRM     C4 9996  15.045   8.304  13.996 -0.0362 -0.0640 -0.3092
 2500GRM     C1 9997  15.046   8.446   0.001 -0.0183 -0.0765 -0.0458
 2500GRM     C2 9998  15.170   8.516  13.999 -0.2414  0.3310  0.3241
 2500GRM     C3 9999  15.172   8.658   0.003 -0.2669  0.3179  0.8367
 2500GRM     C410000  15.049   8.727   0.006 -0.1138  0.5860  0.8426 #(line 10002)
 2501GRM     C110001  15.048   8.869   0.006 -0.0660  0.5939 -0.1623
 2501GRM     C210002  15.171   8.940   0.006  0.0179  0.4561 -0.1660
 2501GRM     C310003  15.173   9.082   0.005  0.3025  0.4524 -0.1486
```

file 2:

```
 2499GRM     C3 9995  15.433   7.952   0.000
 2499GRM     C4 9996  15.310   8.023   0.001
 2500GRM     C1 9997  15.310   8.165   0.001
 2500GRM     C2 9998  15.433   8.236   0.000
 2500GRM     C3 9999  15.433   8.378   0.000
 2500GRM     C410000  15.310   8.449   0.000     #(This line is 10002)
 2501GRM     C110001  15.310   8.591   0.000
 2501GRM     C210002  15.433   8.662   0.000
 2501GRM     C310003  15.433   8.804   0.000
 2501GRM     C410004  15.310   8.875   0.000
```

It is worth mentioning that the problem happens at line 10002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in Stack Exchange - Unix & Linux by Freddy. I am just posting the answer in case someone else is having the same problem.

The problem is that you have either 8 or 9 data fields in file1 and 5 or 6 in file2. Either C3 9999 is one badly formatted field or C410000 should be two fields C4 and 10000.

To adjust the formatting depending on the number of fields you can

use two format strings and switch between them
save the number of array elements n when you split the line and take the last three values a[n-2], a[n-1], a[n]

```
awk '
BEGIN{
fmt1="%8s %6s%5s %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.4f %7.4f %7.4f" ORS
fmt2="%8s %11s %7.3f %7.3f %7.3f %7.4f %7.4f %7.4f" ORS
}
(getline line < "file 1") > -1{
n=split(line, a)
}
NF<=3{ print; next }                                                     # 
print original line 
NF==6{ printf fmt1, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, a[n-2], a[n-1], a[n]; next } # 6 + 
3 fields
{ printf fmt2, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, a[n-2], a[n-1], a[n] }                # 5 + 
3 fields
' "file 2" > "file 3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this trick:

```
awk '(getline line < "file_1") > -1 {split(line,a); $7 = a[7]; $8 = a[8]; $9= a[9]} 1' file_2 | rev | column -t | rev > file_3
```

Output:

```
1GRM  C1   1  0.061  0.071  14.000  -0.5971   0.0204  -0.0724
1GRM  C2   2  0.184  0.142  14.000   0.4831  -0.8709  -0.2204
1GRM  C3   3  0.184  0.284   0.000  -0.7098   0.3449  -0.3952
1GRM  C4   4  0.061  0.355   0.000  -0.4066  -0.4079   0.1701
2GRM  C1   5  0.061  0.497  14.000   0.1844  -0.5441  -0.4893
2GRM  C2   6  0.184  0.568   0.000   1.1631  -0.2289  -0.8340
2GRM  C3   7  0.184  0.710   0.000  -0.4473  -0.2423  -0.3223
2GRM  C4   8  0.061  0.781   0.000  -0.4822   0.0086  -0.4791
3GRM  C1   9  0.061  0.923   0.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
3GRM  C2  10  0.184  0.994  14.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
3GRM  C3  11  0.184  1.136  14.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
3GRM  C4  12  0.061  1.207  14.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
4GRM  C1  13  0.061  1.349  14.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
4GRM  C2  14  0.184  1.420  14.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
4GRM  C3  15  0.184  1.562   0.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
4GRM  C4  16  0.061  1.633  14.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
5GRM  C1  17  0.061  1.775   0.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
5GRM  C2  18  0.184  1.846   0.002  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
5GRM  C3  19  0.184  1.988   0.001  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
5GRM  C4  20  0.061  2.059   0.000  -0.0345  -0.8207  -0.6602
```

Comment: Problem was solved until one more digit was added as below                                                                   
9GRM   C4        36     0.061     3.763    14.000    0.2861    0.2262   -0.2349
10GRM   C1        37     0.061     3.905    14.000   -0.3146   -0.3216   -0.7613
also as below                                                                                                         
99GRM   C4       396     0.553     8.023    14.000    0.7113    0.2907    0.2745
100GRM   C1       397     0.553     8.165    13.999   -0.2221    0.5917    0.1099
how can I solve it ?

Comment: at line number 10002 the second and the third column ha combined together into one column: 2500GRM C3 9999 15.433 8.378 0.000 -0.1438 -0.0609 0.4743 2500GRMC410000 15 8.449 0.000 0.000 -0.4285 0.4827 0.0000 How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

If you need strict alignment, you might want to consider using an explicitly formatted `printf` or `sprintf` statement ex.

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{fmt="%8s%7s%5d%8.3f%8.3f%8.3f%8.4f%8.4f%8.4f"} 
    (getline line < "file 1") > -1 {n = split(line,a)} 
    n > 6 {$0 = sprintf(fmt, $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[7],a[8],a[9])}
    1
  ' "file 2"
GRM in vacuum

192760

    1GRM     C1    1   0.061   0.071  14.000 -0.5971  0.0204 -0.0724
    1GRM     C2    2   0.184   0.142  14.000  0.4831 -0.8709 -0.2204
    1GRM     C3    3   0.184   0.284   0.000 -0.7098  0.3449 -0.3952
    1GRM     C4    4   0.061   0.355   0.000 -0.4066 -0.4079  0.1701
    2GRM     C1    5   0.061   0.497  14.000  0.1844 -0.5441 -0.4893
    2GRM     C2    6   0.184   0.568   0.000  1.1631 -0.2289 -0.8340
    2GRM     C3    7   0.184   0.710   0.000 -0.4473 -0.2423 -0.3223
    2GRM     C4    8   0.061   0.781   0.000 -0.4822  0.0086 -0.4791
    3GRM     C1    9   0.061   0.923   0.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    3GRM     C2   10   0.184   0.994  14.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    3GRM     C3   11   0.184   1.136  14.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    3GRM     C4   12   0.061   1.207  14.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    4GRM     C1   13   0.061   1.349  14.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    4GRM     C2   14   0.184   1.420  14.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    4GRM     C3   15   0.184   1.562   0.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    4GRM     C4   16   0.061   1.633  14.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    5GRM     C1   17   0.061   1.775   0.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    5GRM     C2   18   0.184   1.846   0.002 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    5GRM     C3   19   0.184   1.988   0.001 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
    5GRM     C4   20   0.061   2.059   0.000 -0.0345 -0.8207 -0.6602
```

Comment: it worked well until line number 10002 it changed into :                                       
 2500GRM     C3 9999  15.433   8.378   0.000 -0.1438 -0.0609  0.4743
 2500GRMC410000   15   8.449   0.000   0.000 -0.4285  0.4827  0.0000                                 How can I solve it ?

Comment: the first 3 columns combined together

Comment: @MohamedAbdelaal I based the field widths on the sample that you provided. If the fields need to be wider to accommodate your actual data, then you will need to adjust those yourself ex. change the `%8s%7s%5d` to something like `%10s%9s%7d`.

Comment: I tried that too but I always get a problem at line 10002. I have edited my question and added the output I got in each case, Please check it. Sorry I don't know how to edit the columns in my question to look like the normal questions, sorry for that.

Comment: @MohamedAbdelaal it looks like at least one of your files has *fixed width* columns rather than delimited ones (there appears to be no whitespace between the `C4` and `10000` in line 10002). If that's the case, then please refer to [The GNU Awk Users' Guide: 4.6 Reading Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size) for how to use the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the already two great answers by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) and [schrodigerscatcuriosity](https://askubuntu.com/users/931617/schrodigerscatcuriosity)

Try this ( it is one command split into four lines for readability, just capy all the four lines at once then paste in the terminal then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> ) and see if it works for you:

```
awk '(getline line < "file1") > -1 {split(line,a); l=length($2); \
if (l>2) {$2=substr($2,1,2) OFS substr($2,3)}; \
if (l>2) {$7 = a[6]; $8 = a[7]; $9= a[8]} else \
{$7 = a[7]; $8 = a[8]; $9= a[9]}}1' "file2" | column -t > "file3"
```

Change `file1` and `file2` to your input files and the output will be saved to `file3`

---

**Notice:**

Your column count changes at line 10002 ( column #2 and column #3 become one column ) and the following part of the command fixes this issue:

```
l=length($2); \
if (l>2) {$2=substr($2,1,2) OFS substr($2,3)}; \
if (l>2) {$7 = a[6]; $8 = a[7]; $9= a[8]} else \
{$7 = a[7]; $8 = a[8]; $9= a[9]}
```